# Why was the region split in the following way?

Tags: differential-equations

Consider the paper [Li, Yang, and Zhou - Global stability of an epidemic model with latent stage and vaccination](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.nonrwa.2010.12.030).

Reading the entire paper isn't required. At the top of page 2168 in the journal, the author splits the region in three cases (C1, C2, C3) as a consequence of (16). This is understood for proving global stability of the disease-free equilibrium.

Next, they went on to prove the endemic equilibrium, the same technique is applied  as the disease free equilibrium but this time we have a set of inequalities labelled (22). They then consider 9 cases (C1–C9) but I don't know why they split the region in that particular way. Any ideas? Or was it a typo?

Comment: you link to a paper behind a paywall and say "reading the entire paper is required" --- I doubt that is an effective way to ask a question here...

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I meant it isn't required.. I have edited it. I didn't know there was a paywall.. I had asked a different question on this same paper before and you were able to access it since you commented on it!?